# Errors were encountered while processing: apache2-utils

Tags: apt

Having trouble completing `sudo apt-get upgrade` i get the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package apache2-utils (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Im unable to remove it either.

```
dpkg: error processing package apache2-utils (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2-utils
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

ubuntu 22

How can i fix this problem?

edit:

Tried reinstalling it.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```

> [sudo] password for kay: Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done
> apache2-utils is already the newest version (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4). The
> following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
> required:   libllvm13 libllvm13:i386 libvulkan1:i386
> libxcb-randr0:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 Use 'sudo apt autoremove'
> to remove them. 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 12
> not to upgrade. 1 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/89.5
> kB of archives. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space
> will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y dpkg: error processing
> package apache2-utils (--configure):  package is in a very bad
> inconsistent state; you should  reinstall it before attempting
> configuration Errors were encountered while processing:  apache2-utils
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: … and you did try what the error message explicitly recommends you do, I suppose?

Comment: yes i tried to reinstall it and i get the same error: `dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2-utils
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing isn’t quite the same as installing; you need to run

```
sudo apt-get reinstall apache2-utils
```

Running `apt-get install` in your case doesn’t help: `apt-get` sees that the package is already installed and doesn’t install it again. `reinstall` forces it to be re-installed, replacing missing files etc.

Comment: thank you, i had no idea there was a `reinstall` command